# Is it possible to do integration tests with Robolectric?

Tags: android, tdd, integration-testing, robolectric

I have `MainActivity` and `SubActivity`.

`MainActivity` has a button triggering a `startActivityForResult` calling `SubActivity`.

The `SubActivy` has the responsibility to add a record to a certain repository so that when it calls `finish`, the `MainActivty`, in the method onActivityResult, has to call the `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
```

Now, is there a way to test this *come and go* with Robolectric? Right now I'm able to test the intent called with a click from `MainActivity` to `SubActivity` (using Shadow objects), but I can't see no way to trigger the `finish` on `SubActivity` (with the new element added to the repository) so I can check that the adapter is showing the new element on `MainActivity`

I'm new to Roboelectric so I don't if what I want to test is beyond what this framework is about. Should I use Mockito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have two unit tests for both activities.

The `MainActivityTest`:

1. Check that `SubActivity` intent started
2. Check that `onActivityResult` refreshes the list on `RESULt_OK`

The `SubActivityTest`:

1. Adds record to database
2. Finishes with `RESULT_OK`

For the entire acceptance tests I would use **Robotium** or **Calabash**

Comment: Hi! Actually that's what I'm doing now, meaning I have two different unit tests. What I'm puzzled about is: how do I check that the activity refreshes the list? Is it a good way to get the repository from the Application and then add an element to it and then I call the onActivityResult?

Comment: If you mock your data provider and on refresh return different data then you could check that list size is changed. It's quite hard flow but it keeps your system as a blackbox

Answer (score 3):

Robolectric is not an integration test framework. It is a framework that allows you to write unit tests and run them on a desktop JVM. Eugen's answer is spot on: Test each activity in isolation with Robolectric. If you want to test an entire flow through your application (which spans multiple activities, services, etc) use Google's `InstrumentationTestCase` framework, [Robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium), or [Calabash](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android).